# Enable access to the file system for a java applets in OS X 10.9.0 Mavericks unsafe mode

Tags: java, applet, unsafe, osx-mavericks

With the new 10.9.0 Mavericks OS X from Apple comes alot of trouble for browser java applets in Safari.

To allow access to the local file system for the applet that uses a file selector and access to the file system, the user must go in plugin settings and select run UNSAFE MODE.

While this is a "Security feature" for Apple for the application and clients these raises concerns and will ask why isn't the application secure. T

This is a very difficult situation for a developer/product owner to be faced with the words UNSAFE MODE even if the applet is signed, legit and on a respectable site. 
Codebase , Caller-Allowable-Codebase are properly set.

My question, Is there any possibility to bypass this setting in the Safari browser, to activate it by using any manifest file property or other means.

Answer (score 0):

U have to Enable it in the Pamplet

Click

1. Settings
2. Pamplhet
3. enabel Javer recess
4. Enabel javar access to directory
5. write directory